# Finding Pre-defined variables in Nginx

Tags: nginx

I came across the following [snippets](https://www.javatpoint.com/nginx-content-caching) about handling cache in Ngnix. I understand that the tokens such as `$cookie_nocache` and `$http_pragma` are Nginx variables and are likely predefined. From the name `$http_pragma`, I can guess it's related to the [Pragma HTTP headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Pragma) but I cannot find its documentation.

Can someone point me to the place where these variables are defined?

```bash
proxy_cache_bypass $cookie_nocache $arg_nocache $arg_comment;  

# or
proxy_no_cache $http_pragma $http_authorization;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$cookie_*`, `$http_*`, and `$arg_*` are variable prefixes for accessing dynamic HTTP request content for cookies, headers, and URL query string params, respectively.

- [Alphabetical index of Nginx variables](http://nginx.org/en/docs/varindex.html)